# How to return to the current execution point in matlab when debugging

Tags: matlab, debugging

When at a breakpoint, we often step through for a bit, wandering around looking at stuff, and then want to return to the last line executed.

This is a normal feature in many debuggers, but I'm dashed if I can find it in Matlab.

Comment: If you step you advance the state of the interpreter, and cannot go back. I’ve never seen a debugger that can go back, as it would imply saving the state of all memory for each step made, as well as the state of all external resources accessed. That looks impractical.

Comment: Do you mean something like "Set Next Statement" in Visual Studio? There is no such feature in MATLAB. There is also no "Edit and Continue" option. See [Going to previous step while debugging](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/216347-going-to-previous-step-while-debugging). Very annoying...

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but that's not my difficulty.

I'm stopped at a breakpoint.  I step through a bit, one step at a time, still with execution stopped, then look around various bits of source, then I want to look back at where execution stopped, before continuing or stepping through.

What I want is for the editor/debugger to go to the place where execution stopped.  It was supported in Visual C++, the 'dot' command, and is in the Python WingIDE environment.

Comment: I am using bookmarks for that. Ctrl-F2 toggle bookmark, and F2 jump to next bookmark.

Comment: Rotem, I do fear you're missing the point.

Bookmarks work well, as you say, but they only work within the file that is currently open, and sometimes you can visit many different files while sniffing around at a breakpoint.

Sure, you can always find the place eventually, but it's nice to get there in one shot, as in other debug environments.

I'm beginning to think there's no answer to this, but thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it problematically:**

Use [dbstack](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html) for getting stack trace information.
Use [matlab.desktop.editor.openAndGoToLine](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/366464-documentation-of-editor-api) to open file and highlight specified line.

```
stk = dbstack('-completenames');
matlab.desktop.editor.openAndGoToLine(stk(1).file, stk(1).line);
```

You can add the code to the [Favorite Commands](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/create-matlab-favorites-to-rerun-commands.html?searchHighlight=Favorite%20Commands&s_tid=doc_srchtitle), and create **Quick Access** toolbar shortcut.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm new to Matlab, and didn't know about dbstack.  We can just click on the first line and bingo, there we are.  If the file has been closed it re-opens it at the right line;  though this does not work (R2019a) with the toolstrip Call Stack, which (sometimes) opens the file but not at the right line.

It would be nice for the Masters of Matlab to provide a shortcut, but I'm content with dbstack at the command line.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can add the commands to the Favorites, and create a shortcut in the Quick Access toolbar (you don't have to use the command line). I couldn't find a way to add a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks again for your interest.  I hadn't forgotten your suggestion, but prefer the command line.